# yielding asynchronously doesn't work. tested with DHC chrome client plugin and ajax code

Tags: python, python-2.7, bottle, gevent

I have an api code snippet:

```
@app.route("/do_something", method=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
#CORS is enabled
def initiate_trade():
    '''
    post json
    some Args: *input
    '''
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        yield {}
    else:

        response.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
        data = (request.json)
        print data
        for dump in json.dumps(function(input)): yield dump
```

The corresponding *function* is:

```
def function(*input):

    #========= All about processing foo input ==========#
    ....
    #========= All about processing foo input ends ==========#

    worker = []
    for this in foo_data:
        #doing something
        for _ in xrange(this):

            #doing smthng again
            worker.append(gevent.spawn(foo_fi, args))

        result = gevent.joinall(worker)
        some_dict.update({this: [t.value for t in worker]})
        gevent.killall(worker)
        worker = []
        yield {this:some_dict[this]}
        #gevent.sleep(2)
```

When I run the [DHC rest client](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fdhc-resthttp-api-client%2Faejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm%3Fhl%3Den&ei=lvRNVIHmF8zv8gWp-ICgBw&usg=AFQjCNFMztVKdCZ75zVUp0uKV0YPhUB5yw&sig2=vecWiHtVkKrTebNE-cQfnw&bvm=bv.77880786,d.dGc), w/o the gevent.sleep(2), it gives everything as if a synchronous return value. BUT, with the gevent.sleep(2) uncommented, nothing gets back.
What's wrong?

I thought sleep will cause a delay and "dump" value will be streamed one by one as is available.

Also im no javascript guy but I can read the code somewhat. But even ajax wouldn't receive the code if the server code is not being returned. So I am assuming that negates any possibilities of client side code malfunction and has everything to do with this code snippet.

Please note that instead of yielding, if I just return the value as

```
def function(*input):

.
.
    return some_dict
```

and on api side I do:

```
return json.dumps(function(input))
```

then everything works fine on the client side.